# Samsung Galaxy S4 SCH-I545 official updates via Kies fails with: "Software update is temporarily unavailable. Try again later."

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, samsung-kies, rom-update

I own a Samsung SCH-I545 Galaxy S4 and can not do update via Kies. It says:

> Software update is temporarily unavailable. Try again later.

The phone is sent by my uncle from America and I am from Romania. The phone does not have root. I tried to update via Odin, but it fails too.

What can I do to Update my Galaxy S4 to Android 4.3? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The update for the Verizon S4 USA is set to come eout tommorrow not today.

Comment: Yes? But I got this about a week ago:   Current firmware version : PDA:ME7 / PHONE:ME7 / CSC:ME7 (VZW)
Latest firmware version : PDA:MI1 / PHONE:MI1 / CSC:MI1 (VZW)     It's not the software update? Sorry but I do not know so well

Comment: Uninstall all the drivers you have for the S4 unplug and re plug and when the auto start pops up for windows install the verizon  SUA app see this website for more help http://www.samsung.com/us/support/faq/FAQ00055697/67423

Comment: I did so but the phone hangs somewhere writes: Downloading ... Do not turn off target! We waited for an hour and nothing happened, it got stuck.

Comment: Make sure you have a fast connection and when the phone goes into downloading mode let it sit it can take 30-90 minutes to do it all

Comment: If all else Fails check this page out [link] (http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=46505314)

Comment: Tell me if there are any updates on your device being updated to VRUDMI1 for your S4

Comment: Working Odin file [link] (https://db.tt/qZupCjFT)

Comment: Just FYI the MI1 is 4.2.2 not 4.3

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. So this is not the Android 4.3 update. I'll wait until the official update will appear 4.3.a Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

This was not the 4.3 update. Just a bug fix and added a couple of other features that came on GSM devices. 4.3 set to roll out tomorrow for Verizon customers or at least they claim. I would not hold my breath! If there is anything with Big Red is it will be delayed until they are happy with the release. When I have the notification I will believe it. Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the reply! If you do not install this update can not get the latest version of Andorid it occurs?