# Help me. Can't update my galaxy

Tags: wi-fi, updates, 4.3-jelly-bean, samsung, samsung-kies

I own a Samsung SCH-i545 Galaxy S4 and can not update to Jellybean 4.3. The wi-fi it says: Software update is temporarly unavailable.vTry again later. Kies does not let me update either. I really want the 4.3 update so I would appreciate some help..

Comment: Identical question (first 2 sentences at least) here: [Samsung galaxy S4 SCH-I545 Official Update!](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/55887/16575) Further see: [How do I update the OS on my device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/13510/16575)

Answer (score 0):

Try waiting. It's usually because loads of people are upgrading. There's a limit; you should be able to in the next 2 days.